# Count frequency of events in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, frequency

Within a data frame (see below), I would like to compute the frequency of each activity/event (see second column). The frequency of the events should be shown in the appropriate columns (third until sixth).

E.g. in column 3 (Open Document) and row 2 (user 1) should be written the number "1" and in column 6 (Close Document) should also be computed "1".

Or if user 4 edits a document five times, then "5" should be shown in column 5 (Edit Document) and row 5 (user 4).

Also a loop-function is needed due to a massive amount of users.

```
user  activity                                   Open Document    Read Document    Edit Document   Close Document
1     c("Open Document", "Close Document", …)
2     c("Open Document", "Read Document", …)
3     c("Open Document", "Close Document", …)
4     c("Open Document", "Edit Document", …)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example using `dput` along with expected output. See here on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `table` to *count the frequency of events*. I use `strsplit` to split to single activities and make a `factor` with the levels of all activities:

```
x[,-1:-2]  <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(x$activity, ",")
    , function(i) table(factor(i, levels=colnames(x)[-1:-2]))))
x
#  user   activity Open Read Edit Close
#1    1 Open,Close    1    0    0     1
#2    2  Open,Read    1    1    0     0
#3    3 Open,Close    1    0    0     1
#4    4  Open,Edit    1    0    1     0
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(user=1:4, activity=c("Open,Close", "Open,Read", "Open,Close", "Open,Edit")
  , Open=0, Read=0, Edit=0, Close=0, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. The outcome looks perfect to me.  However, with my syntax (see below) I don't get any outcome. I am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: frame <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = length(data))) 

x <- c("user","activity", "open doc", "read doc" , "edit doc" , "close doc") 

colnames(frame) <- x 
frame$user <- c(1:length(data)) 
frame$activity <- as.character(frame$activity) 
str(frame)
View(frame)

Comment: @Maria26 Maybe its the space or there are `"`. Try to change the activities e.g. from `open doc` to `open` so that you have no space and no `"` in the `activity`.

Comment: sorry for asking again: When I apply your function, just the first "open" will be counted. In the other cells there is just written zero. Do you know why? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Can you show the output of `unique(unlist(strsplit(frame$activity, ",")))` and `colnames(frame)[-1:-2]`. It will be counted only where they are identical.

Comment: The output is >unique(unlist(strsplit(frame$activity, ","))) 
[1] NA
> colnames(frame)[-1:-2]
  [1] "Open" "Read" "Edit" "Close"

Comment: @Maria26 Is there no `frame$activity` ?